# I can't get it to associate with migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to provide an association between Blog and Category but I can't find where I went wrong

Here's how I make `List<Blog>` in the category class to get the association

[image]

This is my blog class

[image]

But when I migrate and update the database, there is no association between them.

I want to know where I might have gone wrong about this.

The SQL image looks like this

[image]

Comment: Please do not add code as images, add it as text. Also please read [ask].

Comment: It would be great if you could include your class association itself in DbContext On Model Creation. However, based on your pictures, It seems that your category and blog seems correct. So need to check your dbContext on model creation defination. It would great if you could share that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

You can try removing the reference from `Category` to `Blog`, by removing the `public List<Blog> Blogs` property.
The reason is that in your current code you have a bi-directional relationship (Blog references Category, and Category references Blog), and that is not well handled by Entity Framework.

If in your code you need to find all the blogs belonging to a particular category, you can do something like

```
var blogs = Blogs.Where(b => b.CategoryID == categoryId);
```

(where `categoryId` is the ID of the category you want to find blogs for)

Answer (score 0):

in Blog class you can add **ForiegnKeyAttribute** to determine the property **Category** is assosiated with **CategoryId**.
Like this:

```
[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
public Category Category { get; set; }
```

and also it's better to use **ICollection** instead of **List** so change Category class like this:

```
public ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to provide an association between Blog and Category but I can't
> find where I went wrong. I want to know where I might have gone wrong
> about this.

Well, based on your shared images and description, it seems your class defination for Blog and Category looks correct. However, you may have incorrect configuration within your application dbContext which you haven't shared but for correct defination you should have following DbContext Class.

**DbContext Class:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This is very important in order to achieve what you are trying.

**For Fluent API Configuration:**

If you would like to use Fluent API Validation OnModelCreating, you can write as following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Blogs)
            .WithOne(e => e.Category)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.BlogId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.CategoryID);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You also can use Fluent API defination if you don't use `DbSet<Blog>` and  `DbSet<Category>`. Either of this would create your foreign key accordingly.

**Migration Script:**

When you would have executed Migration command, you should have following script:

```
public partial class MyFirstMigration : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Categories",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    CategoryID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    CategoryName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Categories", x => x.CategoryID);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Blogs",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    BlogId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    BlogTitle = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    CategoryId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Blogs", x => x.BlogId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Blogs_Categories_CategoryId",
                        column: x => x.CategoryId,
                        principalTable: "Categories",
                        principalColumn: "CategoryID",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Blogs_CategoryId",
                table: "Blogs",
                column: "CategoryId");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Blogs");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Categories");
        }
```

**Demo Class:**

```
public class Blog
    {
        [Key]
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }


public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; } 
        public string? CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** You can add additional property yourself.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)